# Getting the Drupal source code in OpenShift Git repository after installing from QuickStart

Tags: git, drupal, openshift

I have installed a copy of Drupal in OpenShift from the quick start. After installing, when I want to clone my remote repository with the Git url provided by OpenShift, it only downloads the OpenShift QuickStart files. However, in order to work locally I need the source files as well. I am a beginner in using OpenShift and found no solution anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [Drupal QuickStart](https://github.com/openshift/drupal-quickstart) the Drupal core files are not managed by Git, but by the action_hooks that run every time you `git push`. They'll build the Drupal site in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, taking care of configuration (using Openshift environment variables).

To check all the files just login to your app (`rhc ssh <appName>`) and `cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`. You can also download all the app (including persistent files) typing `rhc snapshot <appName>`.

However, the OpenShift way to install modules and themes in Drupal is to use Drush.

Comment: In regard to your last comment, stating that the OpenShift way to install modules and themes is to use drush, can you explain why it says in the README for the repository that in order "to make the app scalable, you'll need to: 1. Check the contents of php/* into your Git repository"?

I don't see how it is possible for me to check in the contents of that directory since it is not in the repository at all. Would I have to download it using FTP or rhc? (I've never used rhc yet.) If I did add it, would I add the whole thing; I really only want to keep the modules under version control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same problem with the Drupal quick start that Openshift officially supports. This quick start solves your problem. It is missing an .htaccess redirect for the installation path, so after creating your app you will need to navigate to /install.php Everything works perfectly after this one hiccup.

https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-drupal-developer-quickstart

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more detail, i.e. an example .htaccess file?